# Ambiguous book titles in Mathematics

Tags: recreational-mathematics, big-list

I fully expect this question to be closed, but I hope it is fun while it lasts.

On my shelf I have a book by Ledermann "Introduction to Group Characters" which could refer to the persona people adopt in groups, and Beardon's "Complex Analysis", which is potentially Freudian.

Are there other mathematical book titles which could belong to completely different disciplines?

Comment: While I agree that it's likely this post will be closed, I really hope it won't be...

Comment: Reverse direction - but the song title "Smooth Operator" almost sounds like it could be about something from functional analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Surreal numbers (D. E. Knuth, Addison-Wesley, 1974) How misleading!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any relevant book titles, but many titles of inner model theoretic papers do qualify:

- G. Sargsyan [A tale of hybrid mice](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/sargsyan_thesis.pdf) -- a detailed study of genetic variations obtained by crossing mice of distinct inbred strains.
- G. Sargsyan, R. Schindler [Varsovian Models I](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/34e9/88749984d45bac2f0ff83a54bd12a67497f3.pdf) -- a catalogue of Warsaw's uprising fashion stars.
- R. Jensen, E. Schimmerling, R. Schindler, J. Steel [Stacking Mice](https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/rds/stacking_mice.pdf) -- a revolutionary approach to the intensive production of livestock.
- ...

I could go on for ages.